Cold water flow is slow from all taps but hot water is fast
I'm trying to find what could be the reason for the weak cold water flow in all taps whilst hot water flow on the other hand is pretty normal.
I have a direct unvented hot water cylinder at home that's pretty old. And the pressure equalising valve is also pretty old.
I'm wondering whether the two above are culprits?

Has it always been that way?  Or has this changed since you've been there.  You might also take and post some pictures of your pipes, particularly those at the water heater.  You might check the water pressure of cold vs. hot.

only thing I can think of is that the cold water comes into the house, diverts to the tank and your cold supply trunk.  The cold to the tank is at full pressure, the cold to the cold supply trunk hits a valve that is partially closed.  This would give the hot supply trunk full pressure and the cold supply trunk partial pressure.

@FreshCodemonger I checked, there isn't any valve that is partially closed on the cold supply

you could reverse pressurize your cold water line.  typically the first thing coming off the city supply is a hose bib so you can determine city pressure.  do you have a hose bib as the first thing?  where are you located as there are different plumbing setups in different parts of the world.

There is a blockage somewhere in the pipe branch that's "all the cold water not going to the water heater" - while a partially closed valve is often thought of, (but you say there isn't any valve there) there are other ways to block a pipe. Corrosion and vastly excess soldering are two, debris is a third.
Here's my classic example of vastly excess soldering, which was on a bathtub/shower hot water line that had good pressure until it was turned on, and then it barely trickled. Apparently for decades until I was faced with it and got sufficiently annoyed to unsolder the pipe until I found the problem.

There is a tiny passage that water was getting through. Irrelevant, but the house also had lots of iron in the water which is why there's a rusty deposit on the surface of the solder blob.
An alternative UK-centric explanation would be if you had a water heater that was connected to the city supply pipes directly, and the old gravity-feed water tank in the attic was still being used for the cold water supply. That would reduce pressure from whatever the municipal supply was to merely the gravity pressure to the top of the water in the tank, which is not much with a standard attic tank. In the past the gravity-fed tank was the more reliable source of water pressure, albeit not very high, since city water pressure might go away completely at times of high demand; as water distribution has been modernized the supply pressures from the city pipes have generally become more reliable and higher. Virtually everyone I know from the UK has removed the old attic tank, but most of them had moved into one or more houses that still had them plumbed in (with at least one report of pigeon contamination of that tank as a good reason to retire it...)
